# Ошибка при сборке boost

Tags: c++, boost, linux-mint

Выполнил `./b2 install`и в конце помимо всего прочего вывелось: `...failed updating 54 targets...`

Программа выдала что некоторых компонентов у меня нет:

```
    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached)
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached)
    - symlinks supported       : yes (cached)
    - C++11 mutex              : yes (cached)
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_auto_declarations : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_constexpr : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_final : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_mutex : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_regex : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_tuple : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_lambdas : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_noexcept : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_nullptr : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_rvalue_references : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_template_aliases : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_thread_local : yes (cached)
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached)
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - bzip2                    : no  (cached)
    - lzma                     : no  (cached)
    - iconv (libc)             : yes (cached)
    - icu                      : no  (cached)
    - icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
    - native-atomic-int32-supported : yes (cached)
    - native-syslog-supported  : yes (cached)
    - pthread-supports-robust-mutexes : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-visibility : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : yes (cached)
    - gcc visibility           : yes (cached)
    - long double support      : yes (cached)
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
    - libbacktrace builds      : yes (cached)
    - addr2line builds         : yes (cached)
    - WinDbg builds            : no  (cached)
    - WinDbgCached builds      : no  (cached)
    - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - bzip2                    : no  (cached)
    - lzma                     : no  (cached)
```

Их необходимо самостоятельно установить?

Кусок лога:

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-7.3.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/list.o
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
                 from ./boost/python/list.hpp:8,
                 from libs/python/src/list.cpp:5:
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: pyconfig.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 # include <pyconfig.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

    "g++"   -m64 -pthread -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -DNDEBUG  -I"." -I"/usr/include/python2.7" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-7.3.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/list.o" "libs/python/src/list.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-7.3.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/list.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-7.3.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/long.o
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
                 from ./boost/python/long.hpp:8,
                 from libs/python/src/long.cpp:5:
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: pyconfig.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 # include <pyconfig.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Приведите кусок лога, содержащий ошибки.

Comment: @VTT Добавил в вопрос

Comment: А на этапе конфигурирования что было написано про питон?

Comment: При  sudo ./bootstrap.sh про питон:

Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /usr

Comment: попробуйте делать bootstrap.sh и сборку без sudo

Comment: Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... ./bootstrap.sh: 225: ./bootstrap.sh: cannot create bootstrap.log: Permission denied

Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details

Comment: а артефакты от прошлого билда удалили?

Comment: От прошлых попыток сборки? Нет. Как их удалить? 
Если речь идет о прошлых собранных версий boost, то их небыло.

Comment: ну тогда удалите всю папку с boost, где вы это собираете, чтоб там точно не было файлов, созданных под рутом

Comment: @VTT Я пытался собрать boost в /usr/local. Сейчас я разархивировал архив в своей домашней папке, но теперь Cmake не его не видит. Куда нужно прописать root boost'а?

Comment: а при чем тут cmake? у вас же сборка bjam. Ну и конечно ни в коем случае не следует ничего собирать в /usr/local

Comment: Я собираю через Cmake, так как использую Clion

Comment: Чтобы раставить точки на ё. Я всё делал по инструкции с сайта boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library. Там сказано делать всё в /usr/local. Использую Clion, там используется CMake. Моя задача собрать boost.

Comment: Там нигде не сказано "делать всё в /usr/local". clion и cmake для сборки буста не нужны. Использование собранного boost в cmake или eго установка (в терминологии cmake) - это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @VTT, я начал сначала. Распакавал архив в /usr/local и пытаюсь сделать это: ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/cheshirecat/libs
ответ: Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... ./bootstrap.sh: 225: ./bootstrap.sh: cannot create bootstrap.log: Permission denied

Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details

Comment: Так не надо лезть в /usr/local

Comment: The path to the boost root directory (often /usr/local/boost_1_67_0) is sometimes referred to as $BOOST_ROOT in documentation and mailing lists .

Comment: В этой фразе не содержится указаний "все делать в /usr/local". С чего это вдруг /usr/local/boost_1_67_0 стало "often" - не понятно.

Comment: @VTT, собрал без sudo, всё равно все тоже самое. Собирал в домашней папке.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка: `./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: pyconfig.h: Нет такого файла или каталога.`

Лечение:`sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`